# How to get a brightwhite color in ncurses?

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

How to init a color pair with light grey background, and bright white foregraound?

init_pair(number, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_WHITE) creates a color pair with light grey foreground and backround, but I need foreground to be really white. I tried combining COLOR_WHITE with A_BLINK (through bitwise OR) but that doesn't work. Ncurses howto's/examples/documentaion couldn't help me either.

Answer (score 9):

You need to set the bold attribute. Call attron(A_BOLD) before you write and attroff(A_BOLD) after.

Answer (score 4):

```
WINDOW *w = newwin(...);
wattron(w,A_BOLD);
<Your statements for mvwprintw, box, etc>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem with python + curses. 
The solution is to enable use_default_colors and then use -1 as background color.

This is python example, but I hope it would be usefull:

```
stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.start_color()
curses.use_default_colors()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_WHITE, -1)
```

Comment: This actually tell to use whatever terminal background color you have. So if you terminal background color is light grey, then it works, but it's only by luck.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a stab in the dark, I'm not very knowledgeable about ncurses:

If there's a function/parameter for turning text **bold**, give that a try! Some implementations of text color mapping use brighter colors in place of a bold font.